# get the base URL and file path from my windows URL by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I tried to get the base URL and file path from my windows URL..But I cant get it..Please correct me..

**The URL is:**

http://sample.com:30023/portal/site/samples/index.jsp

**The current output is:**
http://sample.com:30023/index.jsp?

**The required output is:**
http://sample.com:30023/portal/site/samples/

**Code used :**

```
var baseURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + (location.port && ":" + location.port) + "/";
```

Comment: It appears from your code used that the current output can't possibly end with 'index.jsp'.

Comment: The safer way is to use base tag (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) and getting in js with document.querySelector('head > base').getAttribute('href').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add location.pathname, so it becomes

```
var baseURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + (location.port && ":" + location.port) + location.pathname;
```

Also, why not simply use location.href to get the whole thing?

Good reference at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somthing like this:

```
var sBase = location.href.substr(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer for my question..Thank you

Comment: This is actually not a good way since it fails on a url that ends with for example `"/foo/bar/baz.html?next=/login"`. It is better to reconstruct the URL manually to make sure the query and fragment are not included.

Comment: Addressing concern of @StefanArentz, it becomes `location.origin + location.pathname.substr(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`